# Make a table of content from page number

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdfpages

I have a some PDF files and i wanna make them one PDF by including each of them in order into a Latex file. How can i have table of content which reference to first page of each PDF. Suppose i have two PDF files first have two pages and second one have 4 pages i wanna a clickable table of contents like below

```
pdf1 .......... 2
pdf2 .......... 4
```

and by clicking each number it goes to first page of each PDF.

I add PDFs by `\include{filename}` using `\usepackage{pdfpages}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With option `addtotoc` of `\includepdf` you can add items to the TOC:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
\lipsum

\includepdf[
  pages=1-2,
  addtotoc={1,section,1,Foo,sec:foo}
]{example-image-a4-numbered}

\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={1,section,1,Bar,sec:bar}
]{example-image-a4}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**:
Here's another example with some explanations about the meaning of
the parameter list of `addtotoc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\includepdf[
  pages=3-4,
  addtotoc={
    3,section,1,AAA,sec:AAA,
    3,subsection,2,BBB,sec:BBB,
    4,section,1,CCC,sec:CCC}
]{example-image-a4-numbered}

See \ref{sec:BBB}.

See \autoref{sec:BBB}.

See \nameref{sec:BBB}.

\end{document}
```

The parameters of addtotoc are:

`<page number>, <section>, <section level>, <heading>, <label>`

In the example I included pages 3 and 4 of the PDF and added TOC entries for
both pages. Page 3 comprises one section (with name `AAA` and label
`sec:AAA`) and one subsection (name `BBB` and label `sec:BBB`). Page 4
comprises just one section (name `CCC` and label `sec:CCC`). The label
can be referenced like any other LaTeX label, e.g. `\ref{sec:BBB}`.

One thing that's a bit weird is the `<section level>`. It's a kind of internal book-keeping used by LaTeX and denotes the depth of the section:

```
   part: -1
   chapter: 0
   section: 1
   subsection: 2
   ...
```

Note that these numbers are fixed. Even if your LaTeX class does not have a chapter level, part level will always be -1, and section level will always be 1. For more details about these LaTeX internals see the explanation of
`\@startsection` in the LaTeX source documentation `source2e.pdf`. (Try: `texdoc source2e`)

Comment: could you please explain arguments you passed to ``` addtotoc``` ?

Comment: when i set page number for all file it do not work. but when for all pages i set page = - it works correctly. and for combinations of them still not sure.

Comment: @alfred I added another example with additional explanations concerning the parameter list of `addtotoc`.

Comment: thank a lot. even first example solved my problem.